Bounding norms of symplectic matrix factorisations and non-seperable Hamiltonian flows
Problem setup: Let $e^{hJM}$ be the time-$h$ flow corresponding to the ODE $\dot{x} = JMx$, with $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  A & C\\
  C^T & B\\
 \end{array}\right)$ symmetric positive definite with $C\ne0$, and $J = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & -I\\
  I & 0\\
 \end{array}\right)$ the canonical symplectic matrix. Let $P_i=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  A_i & 0\\
  0 & 0\\
 \end{array}\right)$ and $Q_i=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0\\
  0 & B_i\\
 \end{array}\right)$ that may depend on $h$. The matrices $A,B,C,A_i,B_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric and square.
Question: If $e^{hJM}$ can be expressed as a product of these "shear" maps, i.e.,
$$e^{hJM} = \prod_{i=1}^k e^{hJP_i}e^{hJQ_i}$$
for some $k$ then can you bound the norms $\|JP_i\|$ and $\|JQ_i\|$ from below by some value that may depend on $h$?
Comments:

Edit: Due to Lemma 1 in [2], there always exists a factorisation of the above form for $k=2$, if $A$ is non-singular. I.e., There always exists some $P_1, P_2, Q_1, Q_2$ s.t. $e^{hJM} = e^{hJP_1}e^{hJQ_1}e^{hJP_2}e^{hJQ_2}$.
It would be enough to prove this for the $n=1$ case (i.e., 2D symplectic matrices)
If $\|P_0\|+\|Q_0\|\le \ln{2}$ then the BCH formula for $e^{Q_0}e^{P_0}$ is absolutely convergent. See e.g., Proposition 2.2 [1]. I am hoping that we could bound the norms of $P_i$ and $Q_i$ by saying that if the BCH formula converges, then we get a contradiction.
The BCH series being convergent and assuming $e^{hJM} = e^{hJP_1}e^{hJQ_1}$ means that $$hJM = hJ(P+Q) + \frac{h^2}{2}[JP,JQ] + \frac{h^3}{12} ([JP,[JP,JQ]]-[JQ,[JP,JQ]]) + ...$$
the left hand side has $C$ on the off-diagonal blocks, at $O(h)$, but the right hand side has non-zero matrices on the off diagonal at $O(h^3)$. However $P_i$ and $Q_i$ can depend on $h$, so they could(?) be constructed to get arbitrarily close to the LHS. I am not really sure here, but maybe someone may be able to use this.
If $C=0$, then using the Lie-Product formula:
$$ e^{hJM} =e^{hJ(P_0+Q_0)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (e^{\frac{h}{n}JP_0}e^{\frac{h}{n}JQ_0})^{n} $$
and the norms $\|\frac{h}{n}JP_0\|$ can be arbitrarily small as you can take $n$ arbitrarily large. Hence this answer to my question is no in this case. Therefore, I am hoping the fact that $C\ne 0$ will mean that you must find some $P_i$ and $Q_i$ large enough such that the BCH or Lie-Product formula necessarily doesn't hold.

[1] Biagi, Stefano, Andrea Bonfiglioli, and Marco Matone. "On the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Theorem: non-convergence and prolongation issues." Linear and Multilinear Algebra 68.7 (2020): 1310-1328.
[2] Jin, Pengzhan, Zhangli Lin, and Bo Xiao. "Optimal unit triangular factorization of symplectic matrices." Linear Algebra and its Applications 650 (2022): 236-247.
